# Looking for the 302 redirect code, instead getting 200 OK status code

Tags: java, http, networking, java-http-client

I made a Java program to check whether a web request will redirect or not.
As there are some status codes in HTTP protocol, I need to look for 302 status code that expresses redirect request,
Here is my code spinnet:

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost/test/test_page_1.php");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.connect();
var code = connection.getResponseCode();
```

The `code` variable shall contain the 302 value as my PHP code sets a 302 redirect code and location header by the following code `header("location: pg_2.php")`, but instead, It contains 200 code expressing OK.
I have checked using Wireshark, It returns 302.
What can be the potential issue causing this?

Comment: Client code in java is written 100% right and will work, just tested it myself. Your php code must return status 200 instead of 302

Comment: I Have Tried In Browser, It Works, No Server Sided Issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Java code, you are calling

```
connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
```

before you make the `connect()` call.  That means that the Java client ... on receiving a 302 response ... will *perform the redirect*; i.e. resend the request to the redirect location.  What you see when you call `getResponseCode()` or `getHeaderFields()` are the the details of the response from the 2nd (redirected) GET.

In this case the redirect works, so the response code is 200 and the headers don't include the `location` header.

If you want to see the `302` response and its headers, call `setInstanceFollowRedirects(false)`.

Comment: Ok, Not Calling This Method Dosen't Works, but calling that method with false, works, It Means That InstanceFollowRedirect Is True By Default I Think, Make Some Edits So Anyone Else Having  Same Problem Dosen't Go In Wrong Way,

Comment: Ah.  OK.  I was going from my memory.

Comment: The docs say that the default is the current value of `static boolean followRedirects`, and the initial value of that field is `true`.